# Load all external YAML configuration files in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have an application. It has multiple external (yaml) configuration files (ex; `mongo.yml`, `redis.yml`, etc). I would like Spring Boot to load these, so that they are accessible as expected inside the code base (aka, `mongo.host`, `redis.port`, etc).

This (directory) pattern is non-negotiable, as *every other* service in our architecture can handle it (and is currently using it).

How can I do this?

Notes:

The documentation leads me to believe that this:

```
java -jar app.jar \
  --spring.config.location=config/ \
  --spring.config.name=mongo,services
```

should do what I want: I'm specifying to look in the `config/` directory for the `mongo` and `services` files (presumably, checking for both `mongo.properties` and `mongo.yml`?). However, this is not working; the values are still what appear to be the defaults. Also, it isn't what I want; each file has to be specified, instead of just the directory.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to get close?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there's no simple support for loading multiple YAML files, yet. There's [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) which works great with property files, but for YAML you have to do some work yourself. [Here's a sample](https://github.com/cybuch/sample-spring-multiple-yaml-files) to get you started

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to get everything working except the multiple file part :/ (not sure why it wasn't working before; there's no real change; maybe exact path instead...?) anyway - current plan is to have a different script concat everything into a single YAML; otherwise, I'd need to presume something like `filename.property` and that does seem unreasonable.

Comment: Did you have the chance to go over the [sample link](https://github.com/cybuch/sample-spring-multiple-yaml-files) i suggested? It would allow you to load multiple files. Perhaps the current form does not fit perfectly in your scenario but it's a starting point and you can modify it as you see fit, such as listing a certain directory and retain only `.yaml`....

Comment: I did not. I'll see if I can find the time to try it out; turns out I was wrong about needing to keep them all in different files, so the "normal" way will work.